# Java parallel stream forEach completion

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

I would like to clarify a behavior of Java parallel streams. If I were to use a parallel stream as shown below, can I take it as a guarantee that the line "Should happen at the end" shown in the code below will only print after all parallel tasks have executed?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 23, 399, 939).parallel().forEach(
        integer -> System.out
            .println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", for number " + integer));
    System.out.println("Should happen at the end");
}
```

The repeated trials always print "Should happen at the end" predictably at the end, as shown below. This maybe happening because `main` thread is also used to process a few requests. Is it possible that in some scenario that `main` thread is not used and in that case "Should happen at the end" will print before all the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker` have finished executing their tasks?

```
main, for number 7
main, for number 6
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9, for number 3
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9, for number 4
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4, for number 1
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4, for number 10
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, for number 2
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11, for number 5
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9, for number 8
main, for number 9
Should happen at the end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stream *terminal operations* are not asynchronous. It means that Java will give back control to the calling thread *only after forEach is terminated*. Therefore, what you print after *forEach* is necessarily printed after in console.

Note, however, that if you were to use *java.util.Logger* API instead of *System.out*, output ordering would not be as predictable, as logging API itself *cannot* (for performance reason mainly) guarantee ordering of outputs.

Further reading on stream operations: [Oracle official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).